# Oracle PL/SQL: How to find duplicate sequences in large table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, duplicates

I have a ~20000 row table like this (seq = sequence):

```
id    seq_num   seq_count   seq_id    a    b    c    d
----------------------------------------------------
1     1         3           A400      1    0    0    0
2     2         3           A400      0    1    0    0
3     3         3           A400      0    0    1    0
4     1         2           V2303     1    1    1    1
5     2         2           V2303     1    1    1    1
6     1         3           G2        1    0    0    0
7     2         3           G2        0    1    0    0
8     3         3           G2        0    0    1    0
9     1         3           U900      1    0    0    0
10    2         3           U900      2    2    1    1
11    3         3           U900      5    3    8    5
```

I want to find the seq_id of a-b-c-d sequences that have duplicates in the table, could just be a dbms_ouput.put_line or anything. So as you can see, seq_id G2 is a duplicate of A400 because all of their rows match up, but U900 has no duplicates even though one row matches A400 and G2.

Is there a good way to check for duplicates like this on large sets of data? I cannot create new tables to temporarily hold data. So far I've been trying with cursors mostly but no luck.

Thank you, let me know if you need any more info about my problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the query you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, seq_num, seq_count, seq_id, a, b, c, d ) AS
SELECT 1,  1, 3, 'A400',  1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  2, 3, 'A400',  0, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  3, 3, 'A400',  0, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  1, 2, 'V2303', 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  2, 2, 'V2303', 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,  1, 3, 'G2',    1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,  2, 3, 'G2',    0, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  3, 3, 'G2',    0, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9,  1, 3, 'U900',  1, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 2, 3, 'U900',  2, 2, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 3, 3, 'U900',  5, 3, 8, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT  s.seq_id,
        t.seq_id AS matched_seq_id
FROM    table_name s
        INNER JOIN
        table_name t
        ON (    s.seq_num = t.seq_num 
            AND s.seq_count = t.seq_count
            AND s.seq_id   < t.seq_id
            AND s.a = t.a
            AND s.b = t.b
            AND s.c = t.c
            AND s.d = t.d )
GROUP BY
        t.seq_id,
        s.seq_id
HAVING  COUNT( DISTINCT t.seq_num ) = MAX( t.seq_count );
```

**Results**:

```
SEQ_ID MATCHED_SEQ_ID
------ --------------
A400   G2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming results fit in a string about 2000 characters long, the fastest way is probably to use `listagg()`:

```
select abcds, listagg(seq_id, ',') within group (order by seq_id)
from (select seq_id, listagg(a||b||c||d, ',') within group (order by seq_num) as abcds
      from table_name
      group by seq_id
     ) t
group by abcds
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This returns the matches as a comma-delimited list.

Comment: Isn't `ORDER BY seq_count` non-deterministic as they all have the same count within the group? Would it not be better to do `ORDER BY seq_num`?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, LISTAGG is exactly what I needed. I was thinking of concatenating the sequences into long strings but I wasn't sure about the limitations on string length, my actual table has about 15 columns to compare and up to 20 rows in a sequence.

As an added problem, I'm now being told that the sequences can be in a rotation like this:

    1 0 0 0           0 0 1 0              1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0    =     1 0 0 0    =/=     0 0 1 0
    0 0 1 0           0 1 0 0              0 1 0 0

and I should be checking for these equivalences also.

Comment: sorry my rotation illustration got messed up, not sure how to format it in a comment. Essentially 123 = 312 =/= 132